# Book about a group of magicians hunting a creature

Tags: story-identification, books

The book I’m trying to remember was about a group of children that were being trained magic in a society of other magicians.  One of the biggest things I remember was a chapter where a team of children, including the protagonist, were forced to sift through a pile of dirt and sand, lifting the grains one by one until they were all sorted. I also remember them later running into the woods to hunt down some creature who took one of them away. I’m sorry I can’t remember more. I believe it was released after 2000.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect match.  However, the sorting scene sounds very much like something that happens near the end of *[The Phantom Tollbooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phantom_Tollbooth)*, a classic fantasy adventure novel by Norton Juster and illustrated by *The Village Voice’s* editorial cartoonist, Jules Feiffer.  Other things do not match so well:  the book is quite a bit older than you suggest, having been published back in 1961; and while there is a lot of magic and plenty of lessons for the child protagonist, those lessons do not involve what we would normally think of as learning “magic” (although see below).

*The Phantom Tollbooth* tells of a boy, Milo, who goes on a remarkable adventure.  [As Wikipedia describes it:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phantom_Tollbooth)

> Milo is a boy bored by the world around him; every activity seems a waste of time. He arrives home from another boring day at school to find a mysterious package. Among its contents are a small tollbooth and a map of "the Lands Beyond," illustrating the Kingdom of Wisdom (which will also guide the reader from its place on the endpapers of the book). Attached to the package is a note "For Milo, who has plenty of time." Warned by an included sign to have his destination in mind, he decides without much thought to go to Dictionopolis, assuming this is a pretend game to be played on the floor of his room. He maneuvers through the tollbooth in his electric toy car, and instantly finds himself driving on a road that is clearly not in his city apartment.

Milo gets involved in a quest to rescue the princesses Rhyme and Reason, who have been exiled to the Mountains of Ignorance.  He acts as an agent of by the feuding kings of the Kingdom of Wisdom, Azaz the Unabridged, who teaches Milo about the magic of words, and the Mathemagician, who (unsurprisingly), teaches Milo about the magic than can be done with mathematics.  With Milo are a young watchdog (with clocks on his flanks), Tock, and another rather immature character, the Humbug, whose job is basically to be wrong about everything.

Along the way, they pass through a number of dangerous stretches of forest, including instances where members the trio are temporarily separated.

Among the Mountains of Ignorance, the trio find [the Terrible Trivium](https://study.com/academy/lesson/the-terrible-trivium-in-the-phantom-tollbooth.html), one of the demons who infest the mountains.

> The polite gentleman asks Milo to move a large pile of sand using tiny tweezers. Then he asks Tock to empty the water from one well into another well using an eye dropper. Finally, he asks the Humbug to use a needle to dig a hole through the cliff.
>
> After the three friends have been working for many hours without seeing any progress, they begin to feel frustrated and start to question the man about why they are doing these jobs. Milo uses the magic staff he got from the Magician to find out how long the jobs will take. The answer is that it will take 837 years to finish the jobs!

(The magic staff mentioned in that summary is actually a pencil, which Milo uses to perform the necessary calculation.)

[image: Front Cover]

Comment: That's a great book!